# Lognormal distribution mean

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

[image]

I have no idea how to go about starting this question. The only thing I know is that if A has a lognormal distribution, then B=ln A has a normal distribution but I don't understand how to proceed from here onwards.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1828887/203412

Comment: By the way: Which mean is asked for? The *arithmetic mean* or the *geometric mean*, which would be more natural for lognormal distributions?

Comment: I've obtained the correct answer using the expressions given on that page, I wasn't aware the mean of the lognormal distribution is given by those expressions. Is there a way in which we could have derived the E(X) and E(Y) expressions? Thanks.